# how an RSU can detect a vehicle that enters its transmission range in VEINS

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am new to omnet++ and veins, I want to simulate a simple scenario where an RSU sends a message to every node that  enters its transmission range.

I know that I have to modify the TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc class to achieve this.
But even though I searched the veins frame work documentation, I can't figure out what function will allow me to know when a vehicle enters the RSU transmission range, so I can send the message.

How could I go about this?

Comment: What you describe can be implemented in simulations, yes. However, I'd encourage you to think about how you would build the system you just described in real life.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @ChristophSommer maybe the RSU should broadcast periodic messages to detect vehicles that enters it's transmission range  ?